# Support multiple platforms warnings on pub.dev (Flutter plugin)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a developer of the Flutter plugin.

My plugin was created to make it easy to call the native iOS and Android APIs from Flutter.

As such, this is only compatible with iOS and Android.

However, as a result of publishing the plugin on pub.dev, I received the following warning

```
Support multiple platforms 10 / 20

10/20 points: Supports 2 of 3 possible platforms (iOS, Android, Web)
Consider supporting multiple platforms:

 Package does not support Flutter platform Web
Because:

package:xxx/xxx.dart that declares support for platforms: Android, iOS
Consider supporting these prerelease platforms:

 Package does not support Flutter platform Windows
Because:

package:xxx/xxx.dart that declares support for platforms: Android, iOS
 Package does not support Flutter platform Linux
Because:

package:xxx/xxx.dart that declares support for platforms: Android, iOS
 Package does not support Flutter platform macOS
Because:

package:xxx/xxx.dart that declares support for platforms: Android, iOS
```

How can I get around the warning?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I have a package that does support Web, Windows, and MacOS and it claims I don't support any of these. It would be nice to have more transparency over how this score is determined.